# Error after compiling Python NetworKit script to static binary

Tags: python, compilation, pyinstaller, networkit

I'm using pyinstaller and staticx to compile a Python3.6 script to static binary. I've installed all packages via pip in a virtual environment (venv).

Everything works fine until I try to add the line `import networkit as nk` to the top of my script. Compilation still works, but once I run the otherwise unchanged file, I get the following error:

```
  File "StrategicSolver.py", line 15, in <module>
    import networkit as nk
  File "<my_path>/strat_solver_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "networkit/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
  File "<my_path>/strat_solver_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "networkit/graph.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "networkit/_NetworKit.pyx", line 6, in init networkit._NetworKit
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkit.exceptions'
[19811] Failed to execute script StrategicSolver
```

The module 'networkit.exceptions' should be there (I've also tried installing the package from source via `python3 setup.py install`), so I'm not sure what's going on. I don't have much experience building static binaries from Python so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a temporary workaround by cloning the repository and commenting out any line in _NetworKit.pyx that relies on 'networkit.exceptions' (see below).

```
# from networkit.exceptions import ReducedFunctionalityWarning
.
.
.
try:
    import pandas
except:
    # warnings.warn("WARNING: module 'pandas' not found, some functionality will be restricted",
    #       ReducedFunctionalityWarning)
    pass
```

From there on, build from source as described in their installation guide.